# Magento how chage layout for xmlhttp request?

Tags: php, magento

How change layot for xmlhttp request?
For example if i need "/about" i see full page, if i request this page with ajax, magento use other layout and get for me oly needed information.

Answer (score 0):

In your action, you can test the content of the Accept http header to decide whether to return text/html or application/javascript ... and choose the template accordingly.

Comment: Its possible do with layout?
Like:
page.xml
<xml_http_request>
  <reference name="root">
     <block name="root">
             <block name="content"...
     </block>
   </reference>
<xml_http_request>

Comment: Like this, I don't think so, but you can notice that layout files are associated with areas (frontend, backend). I have already used this for phpunit tests, and it worked pretty well, a call to Mage::getDesign()->setArea('yourarea') would be needed.